# Using dates with sequelizejs to count orders made by customer this year

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this MySQL query that counts the number of orders made by a customer this year:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM orders where year(order_datetime) = year(curdate()) and customer_id = 51;
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to convert the same query to use sequelize. With this code I get back 0 for all users:

```
 db.orders.findAll({
    where: {
        order_id: orderID,
        attempt_datetime: {
            $like: '%' + 2016 + '%'
        }
    },
    attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('order_id')), 'ordersThisYear']]
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log('THIS YEARs ORDERS',  result);
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I get the following error in webstorm also:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release.
> Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues
> /1407 for more info. Arguments: [object Object]

Comment: This is not realted to sequelize, but `moment.js` do you use it in your app? Where? How?

Comment: Btw what is your `sequelize` version?

Comment: no i don't use moment.js at all. I think it has something to do with the $like: '%' + 2016 + '%'. sequelize version 3.18.0

Comment: Apart from this warning does your code work?

Comment: no it returns 0 everytime, it runs but should be getting different answer for each user, everything comes back as 0 though

Comment: What is the query it generates?

Comment: Executing (default): SELECT COUNT(`order_id`) AS `orders` FROM `orders` AS `orders` WHERE `orders`.`customer_id` = '51' AND `orders`
.`order_datetime` LIKE '2016-01-01 00:00:00';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize uses moment to manipulate date. You probably defined `attempt_datetime` as a date field so `%2016%` get parsed to `2016-01-01 00:00:00` date. You should use $gte/$lt operators, not $like, to deal with a date range and you can use momentjs for that:

```
var moment = require('moment');

db.orders.findAll({
  where: {
    order_id: orderID,
    attempt_datetime: {
      $gte: moment(2016, 'YYYY').toDate(),
      $lt: moment(2017, 'YYYY').toDate()
    }
  },
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('order_id')), 'ordersThisYear']
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm can i ask you something. when i get the result back and the answer is in the result dataValues object I am returning it. Is     return result[0].dataValues['ordersThisYear'] the only way to access it or is there a shorter way of writing that

Comment: I don't use Sequelize but I saw there is a `count()` method, don't try to translate SQL queries to sequelize, it lead to weird things. For example, why is there a `order_id: orderID` in the $where? The count will always be 0 or 1 (order_id is unique I guess). Did you try this: `db.orders.count({
  where: {
    customer_id: customerID,
    attempt_datetime: {
      $gte: moment(2016, 'YYYY').toDate(),
      $lt: moment(2017, 'YYYY').toDate()
    }
  }
});`? Maybe that would work.